# python wsgi и cgi

Tags: python, cgi, wsgi

Добрый день,
Нужно написать сайт на python,
что лучше использовать cgi или wsgi? Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как cgi так и [wsgi](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/) представляют собой интерфейс, по которому веб-сервер общается с веб-приложением. wsgi был создан, чтобы можно было бы независимо выбирать веб-сервер и веб-фреймворк на Питоне.

cgi -- простой, древний и не связан с Питоном. Его прямое использование (не через wsgi) нужно только если хостинг не предоставляет никаких других возможностей для запуска Питон-кода.

Я не думаю, что сейчас существуют [веб-фреймворки на Питоне](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks), которые бы не поддерживали wsgi. Так что в выборе библиотек этот критерий не поможет.

Answer (score 1):

По сути эти стандарты похожи, wsgi основан на cgi.
Сейчас лучше выбрать wsgi, потому что это общепринятый стандарт для web-приложений на python. Все современные python web-фреймворки (Django, Flask, и тд) и web-сервера (Gunicorn, uwsgi, и тд) поддерживают этот стандарт.